# Exclude/replace/alias some modules in production build in parcel

Tags: typescript, parceljs

I'm using parcel, and I want to exclude some code from production to save as much space as possible.
I use io-ts to validate the data that comes from the backend. I want that behaviour in test and development builds, but not in production.

(I'm using Typescript)

```js
// this is how it should look in non-production builds
import * as t from 'io-ts';
const schema = t.array(t.string);
export function getData(): t.TypeOf<typeof schema> {
  return fetch('/data').then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => {
    if(schema.decode(data)._tag != 'Right') throw 'ERROR!!!';
    return data;
  });
}


// this is production
export function getData() {
  return fetch('/data').then(resp => resp.json());
}
```

I tried to split this into two modules...

```js
// data-core.ts
export function getData() {
  return fetch('/data').then(resp => resp.json());
}
```

```js
// data.ts
import { getData as getData_ } from './data-core';
import * as t from 'io-ts';
const schema = t.array(t.string);
export function getData(): t.TypeOf<typeof schema> {
  return getData_().then(data => {
    if(schema.decode(data)._tag != 'Right') throw 'ERROR!!!';
    return data;
  });
}
```

...and then many different plugins to import "data-core" instead of "data" if NODE_ENV === "production", but I failed at that.

I also tried with using process.env.NODE_ENV to use either real validators or `{decode: x => ({'_tag': 'Right'})}` hoping that tree shaking will get rid of unused validators, no luck.

Comment: Your alternatives can both be valid approaches. Can you describe a bit more, why it failed and you had "no luck" (error messages etc.)? That potentially gets you a faster and better answer.

Comment: With parcel-plugin-alias I couldn't come up with proper mapping and I think I've tried all possible paths. I hope I'm wrong about this, but it looks like that plugin could only work for external modules ("preact", "redux") and not parts of my own codebase ("./this", "../that"). I also tried parcel-plugin-externals where I specify a function that accepts a path and returns what to replace that module with (I tried replacing with `require('./data-core')`) and couldn't get that to work as well (same symptoms as with "alias" plugin).
I will post error messages when I'm at work after weekend.